# How can i make a column append a string to an increment value and generate it anytime a new row is added

Tags: mysql

How do I create a column that concatenates a string and a column value in a new column and automatically generates the concatenation when a new row is inserted?

Example a table **employees** with **id, serial_no, name, last_name**.

**serial_no** should be generated as **BuStd001**
where **BuStd** is a fixed string and **001** is id autoincrement.

Comment: There's not much point storing derived data.

Comment: @Strawberry is right. Since it can be generated anytime from the existing data you shouldn't waste the processing and storage space. But, if this is a question just to know how to do it, lookup on before insert triggers.

Comment: Go for After Insert trigger, but its lengthy process, as first time you will insert a row and then a trigger will call which fetch the last record from database for ID, after that you have to call a update query which update serial number after concatenate BuStd with ID.

Comment: Thank you @SloanThrasher, Strawberry, KuldeeP ChoudharY

Answer (score 0):

Create your table like this 
[Reference](http://www.webcodeexpert.com/2015/08/auto-generate-auto-incremented-unique.html)

```
CREATE TABLE employees(
id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
serial_no AS 'EMP' + RIGHT('0000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),id),5) PERSISTED,
name VARCHAR(50),last_name VARCHAR(50))
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to work. 
the second line: id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
it says unexpected beginning of statement (near 1)